# QGIS and 'Layer to labelled layer' plug-in

Tags: qgis, labeling, fields-attributes

I'm giving a try to this plug-in and I noticed this:
When you use this plug-in on a layer, it adds a lot of field in the layer table.
The field `LblColor` has a 7 character field, but it needs a 'r,g,b' number that could use more than 7 characters.
In my case I need to write 230,179,251 that are 11 characters...

Is there a way to change this property in the table from QGIS?

If not, I should delete this field and create a new one with a lenght of atleast 12 carachters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **Refactor** Fields tool from the *Processing Toolbox* to change the field properties such as the length:

[image: Refactor fields]

You can save this as another shapefile. Note that when the new layer is loaded into the canvas, you may have to re-enable the label settings by *right-clicking the layer > Layer Properties > Labels* .

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find it...

Comment: @Forna - Awesome buddy! Glad it works :)